# How can you make a widget inherit from another widget? - Flutter

Tags: inheritance, flutter, dart

I want to be able to inherit from let's say a base IconButton that has a few properties. The buttons that inherit from this class should have access to the base class properties without overriding them.

```
class BaseButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final double size;
  final Color color;
  final Function onPressed;
  const BaseButton({
    Key key,
    this.icon,
    this.size = 30,
    this.color = Colors.white,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      icon: Icon(icon),
      iconSize: size,
      color: color,
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to use this base class to generate widgets with little hassle:

```
class AddButton extends BaseButton {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseButton(icon: Icons.add);
  }
}

class CancelButton extends BaseButton {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseButton(icon: Icons.close);
  }
}
```

And I want to be able to easily access the properties of the inherited base class.

Answer (score 0):

Think you want something like:

```
class AddButton extends BaseButton {

  const AddButton({
    Key key,
    double size,
    Color color,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key, icon: Icons.add, size: size, color: color, onPressed: onPressed);
}

class CancelButton extends BaseButton {

 const CancelButton({
    Key key,
    double size,
    Color color,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key, icon: Icons.close, size: size, color: color, onPressed: onPressed);
}
```

No need to override build in AddButton or CancelButton.